# Comparing 2 List Positions & Displaying the Trend (+/-)

Tags: excel

I am having a great amount of difficulty comparing the list position of two lists and having that # displayed in a separate column, like so:

[image: List Difference Trend Excel]

Positions that haven't changed should not display anything. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished? I simply added the Icon Set to help display an upward or downward trend.

Thank you for your expertise and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple SUMIF should do here, like this:

```
=IF(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2=0,"",SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can avoid repeating the `SUMIF` with this shorter formula:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)),"")
```

Comment: FYI duplicating the `SUMIF` can be avoided like this `IFERROR(1/1/(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2),"")`

Comment: This is excellent @BigBen! Thank you! Chris, not sure why but your tip to shorten the equation renders 0.5 instead of 2, and 0.25 instead of 4.

Comment: Slight modification to @chrisneilsen's formula: `=IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)),"")` should work.

Comment: @BigBen that works marvelously! Thank you for the update! Feel free to also edit your answer to include this new version. Thanks! :)

Comment: @BigBen sorry to bother again, but do you know if there is a way to add a condition to ignore new names added to List 2? Say for instance I change "Julio Jones" in cell D11 to "Big Ben"... it will currently give "Big Ben" a value of "-10" which is throwing off my heat map based on "lowest value." I tried to figure this out for about an hour now with no ado-- would really appreciate your help! Thank you! :)

Comment: Try this maybe: `=IF(OR(SUMIF($B$2:$B11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)=0,SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2=0),"",SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)`. Give me a second to figure out the shorter version :) Shorter version: use COUNTIF instead of that first SUMIF, not sure what I was thinking: `=IF(OR(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,D2)=0,SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2=0),"",SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)`.

Comment: That does work! Thanks! I am using the shorter version so will be interested to see if you are able to incorporate that feature into it. I really appreciate your help! :) 

EDIT: Testing shorter version

Comment: Or you can do `=IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,D2,$A$2:$A$11)-C2)*COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,D2)),"")` maybe. I think that should work for your setup.